# G acts freely on X. G is paradoxical implies X is also paradoxical

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-actions, paradoxes

I am proving the Banach-Tarski paradox using a series of small results. For definition of certain terms, see [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#Formal_treatment)

> Group $G$ acts freely on $X$ i.e. $\operatorname{Stab}(x)=e, \ \forall \ x\in X$. Suppose $G$ is paradoxical (i.e. $G$ is equidecomposable with 2 copies of $G$) w.r.t. left translation action of group $G$. Then $X$ is equidecomposable with 2 copies of $G$.

I was given the hint that axiom of choice is required.

Progress: By AC, from each distinct orbit we choose an element so that together they form a set say $S$. We define a map $\phi : G\times S \to X$ as $\phi(g,s)=gs$. We define a group action on $G\times S$ as $h*(g,s)=(hg,s)$. Then $\phi(g_2*(g_1,s))=g_2\phi(g_1,s)$. With respect to this new group action $G\times S$ is paradoxical. Then can we claim $X$ is paradoxical? What is the justification here?

Comment: $\phi$ is bijective